# when i click button, it will trigger twice(in mobile phone)(jquery+phonegap)

Tags: cordova, jquery

when I use `tap` event in my application, it will trigger more than once when i click it. I want to know how to solve it(using jquery+phonegap). In another word, whether I could find a way and using that way, it will only trigger a event once in a small time interval,

```
$('.a').live('tap',function(){...});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.a').live('tap',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**OR**

```
$('.a').live('tap',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**OR**

use [**.one**](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/one).

```
$('.a').one('click', function() {
    // other code
});
```

**OP Comment Response.**

Try using:

```
$('.a').live('vclick', function()
{
   console.log("works once");
)};
```

Also you can test which event is firing

```
$('.a').live('click tap', function(e) {
    console.log("Which Event: "+e.which + " Event Type: "+e.type);
)};
```

For more refer [**jQuery mobile events**](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/api/events.html)

Comment: I have tried your way, but it doesn't work. Especially all solutions work well in computer browser, but fail in phone.

Comment: is there other event on same class..?

Comment: I have found this problem. In the past time, I think if we register the same event on the button, the button will only react one time when the event happen. However, it is wrong.